# How do I move application menu on windows to left side in Ubuntu 18.10/18.04?

Tags: gnome, window, titlebar, window-buttons

I have disabled application menu from top bar using Tweaks. Now the application menu shows on the right side of the application window. I want to move it to left side.

[image: screenshot]

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch Terminal and run the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'appmenu:minimize,maximize,close'
```